# Show that V is not a vector space under vector addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm trying to show that:

$V$ = { ($x$, $y$, $z$) | $2x$ + $y$ - $z$ = $1$ } is NOT a vector space under the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication.

I'm not quite sure where to start with this.

I've started with the vector addition in letting:

$u$ = ($2x_1$, $y_1$, $-z_1$) and $v$ = ($2x_2$, $y_2$, $-z_2$)

...and then trying to add them together, but I'm thrown off by the '= 1' of the original function.

What's the right way to go about solving this problem?

Comment: Is $(0,0,0)\in V$?

Comment: I don't know. The question doesn't provide any other details other than the ones I've given in the question.

Comment: Reworded, if $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ (*that is... if $x=0$ and $y=0$ and $z=0$*) does it satisfy the requirements to be an element of your space.  Does $2x+y-z=1$ when $x=y=z=0$?  Is $2\cdot 0 + 0 - 0 = 1$ true?  If it is not, then that is not an element of your space.

Comment: In case it is not obvious why a vector space closed under scalar multiplication needs the zero vector as an element of the space... because if $(a,b,c)$ were an element of your space, so too should $k\cdot (a,b,c)$ be an element of your space... in particular when that $k$ happened to be zero.  That is, after all, what it means to be closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: As for additive closure.  if $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ satisfies $2x_1+y_1-z_1=1$ and also $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ also satisfies $2x_2+y_2-z_2=1$, we are wondering whether or not $(x_1,y_1,z_1)+(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ will also satisfy the conditions to be an element of the space.  Note... the entries in the tuples did not have the $2$ or $-$ like you have in your attempt.  The punchline here is that $2(x_1+x_2)+(y_1+y_2)-(z_1+z_2)$ happens to equal $2$, not $1$ and so is not an element of your space either and so your space further is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not quite sure where to start with this.

Whenever you're trying to establish that some set doesn't have a particular structure, it's useful to start with trying to find things that result in it failing to have that structure.

More specifically, if you want to show that your given set, under the desired operations, isn't a vector space, then you just need to show that it doesn't satisfy one of the vector space axioms. That's it.

So, we can see that $(0,0,0) \notin V$. Otherwise:

$$2 \cdot 0-0+0 = 1$$

$$\implies 0 = 1$$

which is clearly false. This automatically prevents $V$ from being a vector space.

Comment: That's what I originally had, but I was a bit thrown off, thinking I had to then prove it further using vector addition and scalar multiplication. Does this proof of showing that the space doesn't include (0, 0, 0) suffice?

Comment: Indeed, it does. One of the vector space axioms asserts the existence of a $0$-element that serves as the additive identity of the vector space. So, if you add any vector $v$ to it, you get back $v$. If the $0$ element doesn't exist in the set, then the set does not have an additive identity and, hence, cannot be regarded as a vector space. There's no further work needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little easier to see if we look at the problem using matrix multiplication. Consider that $2x+y-z=1$ could be written $\pmatrix{2 &1 & -1}^T\pmatrix{x & y & z}=1$. Now we can see that for some scalar $\lambda \neq 1$ we have that $\pmatrix{2 &1 & -1}^T \lambda \pmatrix{x & y & z}=\lambda \neq 1$ so the space is not closed under scalar multiplication. Since $v+v=2v$ this also shows the space is not closed under vector addition.